# Xamarin.Forms DisplayAlert not showing on Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This is the code in the constructor of my ContentPage.

```
public partial class MyApp : Application
{
    public MyGoalApp()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new LoginPage();
    }

    public async Task<bool> Logout()
    {
        var confirmed = await MainPage.DisplayAlert("Confirm", "Are you sure?", "Yes", "No");
        //it never reaches this point when I call (Application.Current as MyApp).Logout();
        if (confirmed)
        {
            //Logout code
        }
        return confirmed;
    }
}
```

When I press anywhere, the breakpoint hits the DisplayAlert but it is not showing the alert. On iOS, this works fine.

Adding `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` is not the solution.

Xamarin.Forms version 2.3.4.184-pre1 in all projects (PCL).
Downgrading to 180 stable fixes the issue.

Why does this happen on 184-pre1?

Comment: Can you share a more complete example of the page this is being displayed on and what the navigation hierarchy is? I tried to reproduce an issue like this and I can't. I see the dialog on Android.

Comment: I now see downgrading to 180 is a solution. @therealjohn I will edit my question, because the issue remains on 184-pre1

Comment: Does using `await DisplayAlert("Confirm", "Are you sure?", "Yes", "No")` make a difference?

Comment: @HansElsen That code is totally different. However, it also works for me. https://gist.github.com/therealjohn/98d30f3025899f564391be66f02feb28 I see a dialog on Android. with 2.3.4.184-pre1. Can you show where you calling Logout? Or, create a sample project and upload to share.

Comment: @therealjohn this particular code does not work for me in 184-pre1. The `Logout` method is called in the `LoginPage`. When I have more time, I will create a sample project.

Comment: @HansElsen, ok let me know when you have a sample ready. So far, it's all working for me with how I'm testing.